# How to apply SSAS roles to excel service while using FBA(Forms based authentication)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssas, olap, fba

We have an OLAP project which uses Sharepoint 2013 Excel Services to show excel files that contains external data from SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) cube.

Our Authentication method to login users is FBA (Forms Based Authentication)
Our Goal is to show only subset of data from SSAS cube for each user based on their role which has already been defined in SSAS side.
Because of using form based authentication, roles don’t apply on excel files from ssas, Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we use Customized windows authentication form to handle this topic

Answer (score 1):

We faced this problem and I recall we fixed using Kerberos delegation. We needed the actual user to be passed to SSAS in order to row filter that user. It wasn't simple though. Follow this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/dn194199(v=sql.120).aspx

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the link but I have already read that and because of following conditions it does not seem to be the solution to my problem.

1. Delegation is not required if the connection to Analysis Services is a single hop.

2. Our solution uses stored credentials provided by SharePoint Secure Store Service.

And also this kind of delegation seems only work with windows authentication which we are not using. As I said in my question, we are forced to use FBA(forms based authentication)

Comment: Excuse me man, thanks for your answer, from your answer when u config kerberos, then are you using FBA to login users?
Can you please read this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921086/how-can-i-customize-windows-authentication-pop-up-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: according to this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441671.aspx

FBA with password dont support Kerberos, then kerberos dont help me.